# Chain rule in parametrisation

Tags: chain-rule, parametrization

I couldn't understand the boxed highlighted step that uses chain rule in Proposition $1.3$. How is the chain rule applied in this case? Should't it be $t$ instead of $t$~ in the denominator?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $t = \phi(\overset{\sim}{t})$. Hence, any derivative of $\phi$ will be taken with respect to the variable $\overset{\sim}{t}$. Therefore, the chain rule at a point $u$ will look like:
$$
1 = \frac{d(\phi \circ \psi)}{dt}(u) = \frac{d\phi}{d\overset{\sim}{t}}(\psi(u))\frac{d\psi}{dt}(u) 
$$

and this will be true for all $u$, so the above is succinctly written as:
$$
1  = \frac{d\phi}{d\overset{\sim}{t}}\frac{d\psi}{dt} 
$$

$()$

Comment: I'm still confused, why is any derivative of $\phi$ taken w.r.t. $t$~ not $t$, when the whole composition is differentiated w.r.t. $t$?

Comment: $t$ is a variable which takes values in $(\alpha,\beta)$, while $\overset{\sim}{t}$ is a variable taking values in $(\overset{\sim}{\alpha},\overset{\sim}{\beta})$. Now, it should be clear from the domain of definitions of $\phi$ and $\psi$, which function gets differentiated with respect to which variable.